# SQL Server Migration - Agent Jobs now need to point to SSIS catalog

Tags: ssis, jobs, agent, migrate

I have to migrate SQL Server Databases to a new 2016 version of SQL2016 (from 2008). Since SQL Server now uses the SSIS catalogue, I have had to individually recreate them one by one (since it's an HA instance I have to do it twice, and there are 100 jobs each). Now you might say why not just make a script of all jobs and run it against the new instance, however there does need to be some configuration to each job... i.e connection = oldserver, change so that connection = new server

Please can anyone help, this should be sooo simple

Comment: Can you not script out all the jobs and then do a find and replace on the server names etc?

Comment: Hi Dave, I have thought of that, the problem is configuring the SSIS packages. I have to manually point the job to the package on SSISDB, then modify the connections.

Comment: If you have not set up your packages to use configuration files in the case of package deployment or project parameters in the newer project deployment model you are mostly out of luck.  I would recommend taking this opportunity to convert your packages to project deployment and start using environments etc as you are already going to have to manually adjust all your packages anyway.